# Maven path to resources

Tags: java, maven

I am ending my project and I want to add some photos as Icons.
This project is in Maven.

I just dont know how to get path correctly. I tried all possible paths.

[image]

```
        JLabel fLabel = new JLabel("Text");
        fLabel.setBounds(375,5,50,50);
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(".//resources/flag.png");

        fLabel.setIcon(icon);


        this.add(fLabel);
```

Comment: Do you mean Maven? If so, please add the appropriate tags. Also, please include code as *text*, not as image.

Comment: Could you tell me how You understand this path

Answer (score 0):

the content of the `src/main/resources/` directory from Maven is directly added to the class path of your compiled jar.

So it should work with directly addressing the file without a path.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("flag.png");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your images are in the correct directory.

In your code, instead of passing the path, pass the URL instead as following:

```java
var flagIconUrl = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("flag.png");
var icon = new ImageIcon(flagIconUrl);
```